# Creating a composition that sounds as fusion?

Tags: composition

I created a composition recently while experimenting with different instruments (tabla, electric guitar, sitar, choir etc). I send the file to my friend (close one) and he said that the composition sounds more like 4/4 basic rhythms and is ok ok. But instead of creating such a music that sounds like a 4/4 pattern I want that sound to be focused on more on instruments mixing experiment. What kind of different methods I can use to do that.

I don't want to create a instrumental master piece :), but how to extract out something that I really want people to notice.

Comment: This question is not very clear - the sounds of your instruments are not related to your rhythm, so I would suggest rewording your question to describe what you are trying to achieve

Comment: A (mechanical) way of doing this would be to come up with a series of chords ("a progression"), and then assign one note from each chord to a single instrument. So the chord is now spread across the musicians. Once the progression has completed a round, you can restart it, assigning a different note for each instrument. etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your question title is somewhat misleading because one might think of "fusion" as the musical genre.

So I assume you mean "fusion" as in instrumental melding.

It is hard to give you a magical recipe to create a great composition as it does not exist. And it is not because you are using many different instruments that it necessarily creates this "fusion" or it is not because you use basic 4/4 rhythms that it will never be musically striking!

- What specifically makes the piece "ok ok" for your friend?
- Why did you choose those specific instruments? (tabla, electric guitar, sitar...) randomly chosen?
- Did you pick complementary instruments in timbre?
- How did you play them? Did you play them how they are played in their original culture with corresponding rhythmic patterns or did you "Westernize" them?

Those are some questions you might want to ask yourself to improve on your piece.
There are no wrong answers to those but answering them in your composition can eliminate disparity that could have been generated by mixing different instruments together, and focus your piece into one creation.